Importing selenium
I have had to download Anaconda again after having deleted the previous version from my Mac. However, I saw an error while installing as it claimed that there was already anaconda3 at the default location, therefore I chose a different location.
I then did pip install selenium from a Terminal Window (on Mac).
Thereafter I opened Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda  and typed in the following in the top cell:
from selenium import webdriver

I received the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError  Traceback (most recent .....

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

I was expecting it to import selenium

Jupyter doesn't connect to the environment unless you specifically make those connections, see here. However, the easier way may be to run in the notebook where you want to import, the magic install command %conda install conda-forge::selenium. See here for more about the modern magic install command that ensures the installation run inside a running notebook occurs in the environment where the kernel backing the notebook...

 is using. (This is a general issue with users not understanding using Jupyter in relation to Anaconda environments & as such this is a duplicate of many, many posts and will likely be closed. Please research before making general issue posts, it is the second point made in How do I ask a good question?.)

"I then did pip install selenium from a Terminal Window (on Mac)." I should also point out that mixing and matching package managers is a surefire way to make yourself a headache. You choose Anaconda/conda as your primary package manager when you opted into it. Stick with using it in order to make your environments robust and portable. Reserve pip use for instances where there is no conda recipe. Sometimes it can help if you are troubleshooting but usually it is then a compromise situation & fallback solution that may help in the short-term, but means more far reaching issue that you...

  may end up just making worse.
